# Angular Flex Layout: Holy Grail Design

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to create a simple page using Angular Flex Layout. (Actually a I am removing Bootstrap from the application because I am using Angular Material and feel that mixing them is not a good thing). My goal is to set a main page using the "Holy Grail Layout" by just having a Header, Content and Footer.

```
|------------------------------------|
|              Header                |
|------------------------------------|
|                                    |
|              Content               |
|                                    |
|------------------------------------|
|              Footer                |
|------------------------------------|
```

Following is the code

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="main-container" fxLayout="column">
  <div fxFlex="none">
    <app-header></app-header>
  </div>
    <div fxFlex>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start end">
    <div fxFlex>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.main-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div>
  home works!
</div>
```

**home.component.css**

```
div {
  margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I was expecting that the home component occupies the 100% of the height of the parent, but as we can see by the blue border on the screenshot just below it is not responding on that.

[image]

The home-component div is inserted by angular with the  element as expected, which does not have any styling. But that should not affect in anything the child elements.

If i set the div height on the home-component to lets say 200px (height: 200px) it grows, but i need it to occupy 100% of the parent defined on the app.component-html.

**Different approach**

I tried not take in consideration the < router-outlet > element (similar code was substituted by a div with "content" id) but the result is the same:

**app-component.html**

```
<div class="main-container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
  <div fxFlex="none">
    <app-header></app-header>
  </div>
      <div id="content" fxFlex fxFlexAlign="stretch" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" style="height: 100%">
        <div fxFlex="auto" style="height: 100%; border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px">
          col 1
        </div>

        <div fxFlex="4 0 auto" style="height: 100%; border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px">
          col 2
        </div>
      </div>
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start end">
    <div fxFlex>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The best was able to achieve is to center the div with the "content" ID, but it does not occupy 100% of the height of its parent as the below picture shows:

[image]

I was expecting the fxFlexAlign="stretch" or even fxLayoutAlign="start stretch" instead of fxLayoutAlign="start center" on the "content" div would force it to occupy the 100% height.

Can anyone spot and/or explain me what I am doing wrong? Is this a good approach? Is there a better or smarter way to doing it so?

I am using the official documentation
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API

Can someone points me to an example on the internet? I could not find one using Angular Flex Layout.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I tried to reproduce your problem on Stackblitz and here is the result: [Stackblitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-angular-flex-layout-holy-grail-design?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**app.component.html :**

```
<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="column" style="padding: 5px">
  <div fxFlex="none" style="border:2px solid black;">
    <app-header></app-header>
  </div>

    <div fxFlex style="border:2px solid black;">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

  <div fxFlex="none"style="border:2px solid black;">
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

**home.component.html :**

```
<div fxFill fxLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 2px">
    col 1
  </div>

  <div fxFlex="70" style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 2px">
    col 2
  </div>
</div>
```

**DEMO:**

[image]

And all that was done with Flex-Layout. I hope this will help you.

**PS:** You should be careful not to change the height, this can be a problem with Flex-Layout.
Use "`fxFlex`", "`fxFill`" or "`fxFlexFill`" `instead`. ([Documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation))

I saw that you were using "`fxFlexAlign`" but I do not think it exists for Flex-Layout.
You have to use "`fxLayout`" and "`fxLayoutAlign`" to put in column, or online.
Here is a site that helped me a lot for Flex-Layout ([Angular Flex-Layout Demos](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs))

> Actually a I am removing Bootstrap from the application because I am
>   using Angular Material and feel that mixing them is not a good thing

It is true that using both is not necessarily very good, especially if you use the bootstrap "`col`" with "`flex`" of Flex-Layout, but some bootstrap things remain useful to use as "`margin`" or "`padding`" which are very simple.
So I keep boostrap basically for that.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for. So the secret was in use the fxFlexFill and fxFill.

Comment: Regarding "fxFlexAlign" there is that directive: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlexAlign-API. But is possible that i was misusing it. Thank you again

Comment: OK, I did not know `fxFlexAlign`, I will inquire. If your problem has been solved do not hesitate to validate the answer